# command line jump to the above line when backspace is pressed

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zsh, xfce

I'm not sure how to reproduce this problem each time:

[image]

It just occur occassionally.

**When I press Backtrace on my keyboard.
then the cursor on my terminal go back to the above line  ..**

This phenomenon happened for many years during my work,

I'm not sure when it will occur ,

but I promise to be honest I did not modify the picture manually

The teminator I use is `xfce4-terminal`

The default Shell is Zsh.

Could you tell me what happened to my terminal?

Thanks for your help~!

Comment: Does this always happen, even if you are at the start of the line and have not typed anything? Does the problem also occur with other terminal emulators? What happens, when running a different shell, for instance bash? Do you have some settinggs related to backspace in your `.inputrc`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies~! I did not try other shell.This is my first time to have heard about `.inputrc`